# how to add a sprite an existing scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What is the best way to add a sprite node after a scene has been fully loaded?  The sequence looks like this:
1) I build the scene, GameScene().
2) Some time later, I download backend data and I use this info to build a SKSpriteNode in a different class, NodeBuilder().
3) I want to add this node to the instance of my scene that I'd already loaded.
What's the best way to achieve step 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GameScene`:

```
addChild(yourNode)
```

---

For getting and keeping a reference to `NodeBuilder`:

Creation of `NodeBuilder` in `GameScene`:

```
class GameScene : SKScene {

    var nodeBuilder = NodeBuilder() // Create an instance of NodeBuilder

    func didMoveToView(skView: SKView) {

        nodeBuilder.gameScene = self // Add self as the instance of GameScene that nodeBuilder has reference to

    }
}
```

In `NodeBuilder`:

```
class NodeBuilder {

    var gameScene : GameScene! // This is how you keep your reference

    func addNodeToGameScene(node: SKNode) {

        self.gameScene.addChild(node)

    }

    addNodeToGameScene(aNode) // This is how you would call the method to add a node to GameScene from NodeBuilder
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but you do not understand.  addChiled() can be used in viewDidLoad() or some other function within the GameScene().  I'm trying to load the node after all these functions have run and an instance of the GameScene is already up and running

Comment: @ShaneO'Seasnain You have to make something trigger this then

Comment: @ShaneO'Seasnain yes, you can still use this to add a node at any time while `GameScene` is running.

Comment: @Nik can I trigger it from the NodeBuilder() class?

Comment: @ShaneO'Seasnain to do that you'd have to keep a reference to `GameScene` in `NodeBuilder`

Comment: That's what I need. The code would look like let gameScene = GameScene() in NodeBuilder() but I don't think that captures the instance of the scene

Comment: Done. Thanks Wes!